# Keydown event not handled after button is disabled by click

Tags: angular

In Angular I use `@HostListener` to listen for keydown events on my page. I also have a button, which is disabled after I click it.

My problem is that in Firefox I don't get the keydown events after I press the button. I think it is because the whole page loses focus. The problem is not there in Chrome.

Here is an example of the behavior:

```
import { Component, NgModule, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="disabled = true">Click me</button>
    <p>{{key}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  disabled: boolean = false;
  key: string;

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  private handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.key = event.key;
  }
}
```

How do I keep getting the keydown events after I disable the button?

[Working Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/PiLbWzj8NnQQuity?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in Chrome.

Comment: I have used Firefox. I'm sorry I didn't specify that in the question. I can see, that it is not a problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce on chrome using the plunker. What's your browser ?

Wathever you could try to [change the focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus). Something like :

```
import { Component, NgModule, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="disable()">Click me</button>
    <p>{{key}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  disabled = false;
  key: string;

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.key = event.key;
  }

  disable() {
     this.disabled = true;
     document.activeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using Firefox. Sorry for not specifying that. Unfortunately setting the focus on document.body doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try with document.activeElement.blur(); it works for me on firefox